# R apply loop with return list

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I tried to replace `for` loop by `apply` loop in an existant R script. Nevertheless, my old function returns multiple dataFrames list like that `return(list(df1,df2))`. For some details, an example is presented below :

Old Script:

```
MyFunction = function(input){
  df1=array(NA,c(0,1))
  df2=array(NA,c(0,1))
  for(i in 1:n){
    ...
    df1 = rbind(df1,action1(input))
    df2 = rbind(df2,action2(input))
  }
return(list(df1,df2))
```

New Script:

```
Object = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:n,function(i){
  df1 = action1(input)
  df2 = action2(input)
  return(list(df1,df2))
}))
```

I obtain :

```
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
 [1,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
 [2,] List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
 [3,] …
```

I have no idea to resolve my problem. Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advances,

B.Gees

Comment: What are *action1()* and *action2()*? And those are not dataframes in first function but arrays, two very different data structures.

Comment: Sorry, my example is not expressive. I used `...` to different action from input dataFrame and `action1` and `action2` for two different calculations on my transformed dataFrame. I agree with you about the differentiation between `array` and dataFrame but for me is a simple solution to initialize dataFrame and obtain the good column headers by a simple concatenation of the first result dataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do.call(rbind, ...)` is usually used for row bind a list of data frames/matrices. You have a list of list of data frames, and you want to bind them accordingly, you can try the following pattern.

```
Object = do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, lapply(1:n,function(i){
  df1 = action1(input)
  df2 = action2(input)
  return(list(df1,df2))
})))
```

`do.call(Map, ...)` passes all lists returned by `lapply` as arguments to `Map` which then pass all data frames from the same positions to `rbind`. i.e. all `df1` will be bound together and all `df2` will be bound together.

Comment: I test and it runs. Thanks a lot Psidom.